# How to use correct the MySQL nodejs modul in Appcelerator?

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I using to a few days the Appcelerator Studio under Windows 8.1 with Samsung A5. Now I would like using the mysql nodejs modul. I readed in the net that copy the dir of mysql copy to under my Resources dir.
So, my folder looks like that:

```
Projectname
+-- Resources
    +-- android
    +-- mysql
    |   +-- lib
    |   |   +--- ...
    |   +-- node_modules
    |   |   +--- ...
    |    \- index.js
     \- app.js
```

And here is my app.js:

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'domain',
      user: 'user',
      password: 'password',
      database: 'database'
    });

    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            alert("Error on mysql connect: " + err.stack);
            return;
        }
    });

    alert("Mysql connect is correct.");

    connection.end();
```

The project is installed on Samsung, but throw an error on start: mysql module is not found.

What is wrong.
Please, help me!

Thanks for your help and sorry my english!

Comment: added "general" answer about mysql, but also added how you can get your mysql node module to work :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as MySQL on iOS/Android in Titanium. The database that is there is SQLite. You can read about SQLite in the [documentation of Appcelerator](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Working+with+a+SQLite+Database).

It also is not a module, but a `good old` API. Example (from the docs)

```
var db = Ti.Database.open('TiBountyHunter');
db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fugitives(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, captured INTEGER, url TEXT, capturedLat REAL, capturedLong REAL);');
db.close();
```

If you have a module named `mysql` you should put it in the `lib` folder to get it to work. However, this can be difficult if it has Node dependencies. You can then use [Titaniumifier](https://github.com/smclab/titaniumifier)

Comment: **Thanks Rene for your answer!**
The "mysql" is an legal nodejs modul. Here is the URL: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)
In the mysql dir there is an index.js, an 'lib' and a "node_modules" dirs. I copyied the mysql dir to Resources/lib directory, but it isn't work.

Comment: have you looked into Titaniumfier? Titanium doesn't contain Node. Of your mysql module uses any dependencies they also need to be included.

Comment: So, I don't use Titanium. I using Appcelerator Studio, and this is recognize my nodejs and configurable in Help / Preferences.
And yes, I saw the Titaniumfier, but I don't know, how to use to connect from my Android app to an MySQL database.

Comment: Appcelerator Studio is build on Eclipse. Appcelerator Studio integrates the Appcelerator CLI that builds Titanium Apps. Yes, you use Titanium. An no, there is no Node involved in the apps themselves, only during builds. There simply is no MySQL inside a Titanium App, nothing whatsoever. So unless you somehow are able to install MySQL inside an app / remotely connect to a database, this won't work and you'll have to use SQLite. Hence the beginning of my answer